# How to make the Formik call a function when the form is invalid

Tags: react-native, formik

I have a login form, and when the user/password are not correct I call a function to make a animation in a component, but this function is only called when I pass the user/password to my api and it does not match with the information in the database. I want to call the function when the form is not valid too (before go to my api).

I'm using the formik lib to validate my form, and with that I show the message error, but I don't know how to make it call my animation function. My code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { login } from '../../store/actions/user'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Animated,
    Easing
} from 'react-native'
import { Formik } from 'formik'

import AuthContainer from '../../components/Auth/AuthContainer'
import AuthTitle from '../../components/Auth/AuthTitle'
import AuthButton from '../../components/Auth/AuthButton'
import AuthInput from '../../components/Auth/AuthInput'
import AuthHeader from '../../components/Auth/AuthHeader'
import SpeechBubble from '../../components/Auth/SpeechBubble'
import { validationSchema } from './validationSchema'

import styles from '../../assets/css/styles'

class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        shakeAnimation: new Animated.Value(0)
    }

    componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
        if(prevProps.isLoading && !this.props.isLoading && this.props.token){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')
        }
        else if(this.props.loginError && this.props.isLoading){
            this.handleAnimation()
        }
    }

    login = () => {
        this.props.onLogin({ ...this.state })
    }

    navigateToRegister = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')
    }

    handleAnimation = () => {
        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.timing(this.state.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 10, duration: 80, useNativeDriver: true }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.shakeAnimation, { toValue: -10, duration: 80, useNativeDriver: true }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 10, duration: 80, useNativeDriver: true }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 0, duration: 80, useNativeDriver: true })
          ]).start() 
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                    this.setState({ email: values.email, password: values.password })
                    this.login()
                }}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                validateOnBlur={false}
                validateOnChange={false} >

                        {formikProps => (
                            <AuthContainer>
                                <AuthHeader />

                                <SpeechBubble>
                                    <Animated.View
                                        style={{ transform: [{translateX: this.state.shakeAnimation}] }}>
                                    <AuthTitle 
                                        text={
                                                formikProps.errors.email ?
                                                formikProps.errors.email :
                                                formikProps.errors.password ?
                                                formikProps.errors.password :
                                                !this.props.loginError ? 
                                                'Olá! Cadastrou sua conta usando e-mail e senha? Insira-os aqui:' : 
                                                this.props.loginError} 
                                        styleTitle={!this.props.loginError && formikProps.isValid ? styles.bodyText :
                                            [styles.bodyText, styles.bodyTextError]}/>
                                    </Animated.View>
                                    <AuthInput
                                        placeholder='Seu e-mail'
                                        keyboardType='email-address'
                                        autoFocus={true}
                                        autoCorrect={false}
                                        autoCapitalize='none'
                                        returnKeyType='next'
                                        value={formikProps.values.email}
                                        onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('email')}
                                        onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur('email')}
                                        blurOnSubmit={false} />

                                    <AuthInput 
                                        placeholder='Sua senha'
                                        secureTextEntry={true}
                                        returnKeyType='go'
                                        value={formikProps.values.password}
                                        onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur('password')}
                                        onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('password')} />

                                    <AuthButton title='Entrar' onPress={formikProps.handleSubmit} />

                                    <View style={styles.bodyBottom}>
                                        <Text style={styles.bodyLink}>Esqueci minha senha</Text>

                                        <Text style={styles.bodyLink} onPress={this.navigateToRegister}>
                                            Ainda não cadastrei uma conta
                                        </Text>
                                    </View>
                                </SpeechBubble>
                            </AuthContainer>
                        )}
            </Formik>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => {
    return {
        isLoading: user.isLoading,
        token: user.token,
        loginError: user.loginError,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLogin: user => dispatch(login(user))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Answer (score 0):

The place where you pass `formikProps.handleSubmit`, just pass a function that calls you api and after calls `formikProps.handleSubmit`

```
<AuthButton 
    title='Entrar' 
    onPress={() => {
        // call what you want

        // call formik handleSubmit after
        formikProps.handleSubmit()
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: I decided to not use formik and make my own validation, thanks any way